# Как сохранить положение дочерней формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Необходимо запоминать положение формы с красной рамкой после её закрытия.

Реализовал с помощью .ini файла. Загрузка из файла:

```
    infoF.Width = Convert.ToInt32(ini.GetValue("Settings", "infoWidth"));
    infoF.Height = Convert.ToInt32(ini.GetValue("Settings", "infoHeight"));
    infoF.DesktopLocation = new System.Drawing.Point(Convert.ToInt32(ini.GetValue("Settings", "infoLocationX")), Convert.ToInt32(ini.GetValue("Settings", "infoLocationY")));
```

Загрузка в файл

```
   private void info_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        IniStructure ini = new IniStructure();


        ini = IniStructure.ReadIni(Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\Temp\\" + "conf.ini");

        ini.ModifyValue("Settings", "infoWidth", Width.ToString());
        ini.ModifyValue("Settings", "infoHeight", Height.ToString());
        ini.ModifyValue("Settings", "infoLocationX", this.DesktopLocation.X.ToString());
        ini.ModifyValue("Settings", "infoLocationY", this.DesktopLocation.Y.ToString());

        IniStructure.WriteIni(ini, Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\Temp\\" + "conf.ini");
    }
```

Но вот сохранил значения положения:

[image: 1]

При следующем запуске программы форма почему-то вот здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вполне возможно что эта форма дочерняя и всё из-за этого, подскажите направление.

Comment: в каком событии происходит получение данных из Ini файла?

Comment: при создании главной формы, запускаю функцию которое всё это извлекает и задаёт размеры формы с красной рамкой

Comment: приложите код создания формы с красной рамкой и как вы задаете ее позицию полученную из ini файла

Comment: добавь 
infoF.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
перед 
 infoF.DesktopLocation = new System.Drawing.Point

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_nqaqLKc690YzFyTlo1OXZSOVU

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо! Добавил строчку, изменил DesktopLocation на Location, переместил код для записи в файл в обработчик Resize формы и всё заработало

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!

Comment: @NMD оформите ответ хотя бы кратко. А если добавите описание почему это помогло, будет еще лучше.

Comment: @rdorn, добрый вечер! оформил в виде ответа

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изначально производилась установка значения свойства DesktopLocation, которое отвечает за положение формы на экране

```
infoF.DesktopLocation = new System.Drawing.Point(Convert.ToInt32(ini.GetValue("Settings", "infoLocationX")), Convert.ToInt32(ini.GetValue("Settings", "infoLocationY")));
```

но т.к. значение свойства **StartPosition** у формы было не равно значению **FormStartPosition.Manual** (говорит форме о том, что позиция окна будет задана в ручную) значения которые были указаны в переменной **DesktopLocation** игнорировались и заменялись стандартными значениями Windows.

Так же стоит отметить тот факт, что при тестировании было достаточно добавление строки

```
infoF.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

для того, чтобы форма отображалась там где нам это было необходимо, но в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition(v=vs.110).aspx) сказано, что необходимо ни только установить значение StartPosition в Manual, но и задать значение Location(как и сделал автор вопроса.), а не DesktopLocation (у меня данный вариант работал исправно).

**DesktopLocation** - Координаты рабочего стола основаны на рабочей области экрана, который исключает панели задач.

**Location** - Координаты рабочего стола относительно верхнего левого угла монитора.